# Bootstrap: Trouble using modal for showing dynamic data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list created dinamically using php

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ //$row is a row fetched from my database
<tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['surname']?></td>
   <td><a href="#Modal" <?php echo "id= " . $row['username'] ?> class="btn btn-small btn-info" data-toggle="modal" > Vedi</a></td>
</tr>
}
```

Modal is something like this:

```
<div id="Modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</a>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">user information</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="loadInfo">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span12">

         <!-- my php code here -->

        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My php code must be referred to a precise user. So I need that the Modal can receive this the id of the  in order to execute the proper php code.

How can I obtain this result?

Comment: set a jQuery click handler on the links that updates whatever it is you want in the modal. Can't run php in browser so not entirely clear what your expectations are

Comment: @Joseph82 I am facing the same problem, I am a newbie and don't know how to implement it. I got a dynamic list but when I display it in modal using youtube iFrame, then only the first video is played rest are not. Can you please share the code so that I can get help from that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you give your modal a dynamic id.  in a php query while loop set the modal id to your query row id for example.  i just answered essentially the same question here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081592/bootstrap-3-modal-using-php-recordset-data/28081695#28081695

If you want, i would be happy to write you both what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign the values of the user info to javascript variables. Add a data attribute to the modal toggle buttons like `data-user_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>` and make a jquery click handler to update the modal's content to match the button you clicked.